Training a LLM to execute functions
I want develop a chatbot that is able to perform actions and answer questions in a given Smart Home environment.
I am curious how to do this with an LLM. How can I customize/train a model to execute code?
Just a simple example: When I tell the chatbot "turn on the light in the living room" it should answer "I will turn on the light in the living room" and at the same time turn it on in the background (assuming I have an API / code that I am able to call).
Are there some resources or even examples you can share to learn about the process?
I know a bit about customizing models like adding a System Message or adjusting the temperature of the model and I also trained an LLM to generate software requirements before. But I don't know how to train a model to perform an action like turning a smart device on or off.
I am currently using Ollama to manage and customize models.

you can prompt your llm with something like respond
Respond with JSON of this format, when given any request
{
'action': "intent / action to perform like turn-on-fan",
'device': "id of device / any identifier"
}
Human:
Example turn on Kitchen Fan
Response:
{
'action': 'fan-on',
'device': 'kitchen-fan'
}
-----
Human:
<Your Command>

If the LLM is powerful enough it should be able to perform this task.

Fine-tuning the LLM won't be required for simple tasks like this.

Regarding the API, using Lang Chain, and some pydantic you can extract the request json and perform the device control api calls.
As for the resources:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling

The first answer that you can describe output format for powerful LLM in system prompt, is correct.
However there are specific models/APIs for that, called function calling.
You can use commercial ones like Mistral or pretrained models like NexusRaven, which you can use locally, e.g. with LM Studio.
